# How to prevent extraction of constants from radical sign?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

To me, the expression `Sqrt[2]Sqrt[x]` is more complex than `Sqrt[2x]`. But even if I merely input the latter, I get the former as output. I'd like to simplify expressions where such square roots could get additional terms inside, so `Inactivate` or `Defer` don't really help. See e.g. this:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 x] Sqrt[y], x > 0 && y > 0]
```

This gives me `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x y]` as a result, while I'd prefer `Sqrt[2 x y]`. Even if I specify complexity function like the following, it still doesn't help:

```
FullSimplify[Sqrt[2 x] Sqrt[y], x > 0 && y > 0, 
 ComplexityFunction -> (Times@@ImageDimensions@Rasterize[#] &)]
```

And this is despite these results:

```
Times@@ImageDimensions@Rasterize[Sqrt[2 x]]
Times@@ImageDimensions@Rasterize[HoldForm[Sqrt[2 x]]]
```

> 1323
>
> 903

I've looked at `SystemOptions["SimplificationOptions"]`, but haven't found anything related to this type of simplification.
Is there any way to prevent such splitting of constants from the radical?

Answer (score 4):

Even when a simplification would have returned `Sqrt[2 x y]`, Mathematica would have further evaluated this  to `Sqrt[2] Sqrt[x y]`. So simplification will not help you. What we can do is to print the result in the form you want to see it:

```
MakeBoxes[Times[z:(Power[_, Rational[1,2]]..)], StandardForm] := 
  RowBox[{SqrtBox[ToBoxes[ Times @@ {z}[[All,1]]]]}]

Sqrt[2 x] Sqrt[y]

(* Sqrt[2 x y] *)
```

But be careful: the output now looks like being a square root of a product. However, it still is the product of some square roots:

```
FullForm[%]

(* Times[Power[2,Rational[1,2]],Power[x,Rational[1,2]],Power[y,Rational[1,2]]] *)
```